# edit title (mat-expansion-panel-header) on the go in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, formarray

I want to change my title on live

This is my current image will look like

[image]

HTML Code

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of formData.groups">
        <!-- Panels-->
        <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel cdkDrag>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    {{group.formGroupName}}
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        
        </mat-accordion>
    </ng-container>
```

i was try to add input like below so I can modify the panel text when the application in live

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="group.formGroupName" class="editable" />
```

But this is not working

This is my Ts.

```
    formData: Form = {
        formGroupName: 'form',
          groups: [
            {
                formGroupName: 'personalDetails',
                fields: [
                {
                 formControlName: 'firstName',
                  type: 'Text',
                  required: false,
                  label:'FirstName',
                  locked: true
                }
               ]
              },
              {
                formGroupName: 'contactDetails',
                 fields: [
                  {
                    formControlName: 'address1',
                    type: 'Text',
                    required: false,
                    label:'Address 1',
                    locked: true
                  }
               ]
             }
            ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="group.formGroupName" [value]="group.formGroupName" class="editable" />
```